# Uploaded file is null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC4, a file-upload view is always sending null to the controller.
I have no idea why, I don't know how to fix it and searching has proven unfruitful...

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult uploadCustomImage(int id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("uploadCustomImage", "W", new { id=ViewBag.id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name="uploadingimage" }))
{ 
    <input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
    @Html.SubmitButton()
}
```

It enters into the controller fine, so routing is all good. But file is always null. I've tried several different things: renaming the input/object, not using a file argument and calling this:
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];
(which also turns out null)

I tried including a formcollection as a parameter (with and without unnecessary form elements). Still this file is null.

I am of course selecting a file before I press submit =P I've tried multiple files; with very basic filenames (no weird unicode, even no spaces) and also weirder ones. Large files, small files.

Everything comes out null! Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: on a longshot, is it a big file?

Comment: and another longshot, change browsers. does that change anything?

Comment: I tried a few files, the smallest being 3.58kB

Comment: Tested it in IE9 and Firefox, yielding concordant results of null.

Answer (score 0):

your names don't line up... you need to model bind your file control called "postedFile" in your controller

Comment: Ah thanks, that was from trying to call it something other than file. They've both been 'postedFile' and 'file' (at the same time) and produced identical results.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("uploadCustomImage", "W", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" />
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult uploadCustomImage(int id, HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload)
{}
```

**[EDIT]**

I've just implemented an upload feature in a project I'm working on and it works.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "MY_CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file"  id="UploadedXlsFile" name="UploadedXlsFile"/>

    <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>

}


public ActionResult Import()
{
    if (Request.Files["UploadedXlsFile"].ContentLength > 0)
    {
       .............Do stuff ................
    }
}
```

The previous code works for me. If I put a break point inside the Action method, I can see the file isn't null.

Comment: You want me to change the name of the action? OK...  still null.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. Could it be the name you use for the file attribute? Try a different name for the file input.